# CanOpenURL without add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Tags: ios, openurl

I have a question that I wanna open other apps in my app,
(a MDM Like App),
but after **iOS 9**,
using CanOpenURL to check other apps need to add Schemes in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes,
I get my apps list on websrevice so I can't add them into plist,
is there any solution to use CanOpenURL to check other apps is install or not **without add scheme in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIApplication.open(_:​options:​completion​Handler:​)` whithout specifying the URLS in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. That key is only used for `can​Open​URL(_:​)`.
See [Apple's documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl):

> ... Unlike this method, the `open​URL(_:​)` method is not constrained by the `LSApplication​Queries​Schemes` requirement. That method works if an app is available to open the URL, whether or not you have declared the scheme.

---

**Update**

So if you need `canOpenURL`, you will also need those `LSApplication​QueriesSchemes` entries in the `.plist`, otherwise `canOpenURL` will always return `false`. This restriction has been implemented in iOS 9 (I think) to prevent malicious apps from *sniffing around*  the installed phone.

Since there is no way to add entries at runtime and wildcards aren't possible, the only solution is to directly call `openURL` and check if it was successful or not. If your webservice and MDM guarantees that the apps being called are installed, this could be a viable work-around.

You could also implement something like [x-callback](http://x-callback-url.com/). Think of the following:

- The central (MDM-like) app registers a URL like "register-app://" where other apps can register themself with their own (callback) URL Scheme
- The other app calls "register-app" and provides it's own (callback-) scheme

  - It has to be started manually once to do so
- The MDM-like app stores the "callback-URLS" in a database
- The MDM-like app now directly uses `openURL`
- There is no need for the webservice any more

Or your MDM (the real MDM) could send a push notification to inform about newly installed apps and their URL scheme.

Nevertheless, it's all just tricks to circumvent the restrictions apple thought of...

Comment: My fault,I must use CanOpenURL to check that App is installed or not...